# Scala given list map / filter / take without iterating over whole list

Tags: scala

Given a list of elements , I need to map(get response) / filter (check response is valid) / take(take only first valid n elements) without iterating over whole list.

For example I have a List of 10 elements.
1st is valid
2nd is invalid
3rd is valid
4th and subsequent are valid

Sample code

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
    .map{x => println("Some req/res"); x}
    .filter{_ % 2 == 0} //filter for valid responses
    .take(3) //take first 3 valid ones
```

I would expect println("Some req/res") to be printed only 4 times, but its printed all 20 times.
How do I get first n valid elements without going over the whole list?

Right now I am using a for-loop with accumulator list and check its size til its filled with valid response.  I am looking for more functional approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of either `map` or `filter` for `List`, each function must iterate the entire list. Specifically for `map` it will return a new `List` resulting from applying the given function f to each element of this list and collecting the results.

The `map` will then return a new List with the same values as the initial list with the side effect of printing "Some req/res" once for each element.

```
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)

scala>.map{x => println("Some req/res"); x}
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

The `filter` will then produce a new list where only the elements that match the predicate are returned.

```scala
scala> .filter{_ % 2 == 0}
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
```

Finally, the `take(3)` will create a new List with at most 3 elements.

```scala
scala> .take (3)
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

If you want to delay the effects of `map` and `filter`, you need a different data type. You can use `Stream` in this case, but use a final `toList` to collect the results to a list.

```scala
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20).toStream
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> .map{x => println("Some req/res"); x}
Some req/res
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> .filter{_ % 2 == 0}
Some req/res
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(2, ?)

scala> .take(3)
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(2, ?)

scala> .toList
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
Some req/res
res13: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: I accepted this answer also because it also provides the solution I want. Thanks @Freddie

Answer (score 3):

You want to make the result a lazily evaluated collection. One easy way to do this is add `.view`.

```
val res = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
  .view
  .map{x => println("Some req/res"); x}
  .filter{_ % 2 == 0} //filter for valid responses
  .take(3) //take first 3 valid ones
//res: scala.collection.View[Int] = View(<not computed>)
```

You'll notice that now you get no `println()` output. That's because the result hasn't been "forced" yet. But it is still a good result that you can process further.

If just want to see the result there are many ways to force the evaluation. Here's a simple one.

```
res.toList
//Some req/res
//Some req/res
//Some req/res
//Some req/res
//Some req/res
//Some req/res
//res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks this is the solution that I was looking for.

Comment: @jwvh If I force computation via `toArray`, then I would see 12 times the log message (https://imgur.com/a/8rJcM1r), so one should be very careful about such kind of side effects.

Answer (score 2):

as others have said, both `.map` and `.filter` will need to iterate through all the list.

A easy way to print only 3 times would be to change the order of your operations:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
    .filter{_ % 2 == 0} //filter for valid responses
    .take(3) //take first 3 valid ones
    .map{x => println("Some req/res"); x}
```

This way, it will only print 3 times (but filter will still iterate through all the collection

If you really want to avoid iterating through the whole list, try using a lazy collection, like `Stream` (of if you are using newer scala versions, `LazyList` https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2018/06/13/scala-213-collections.html#lazylist-is-preferred-over-stream)